# Unable to install SUMO-0.32 with NS3.27

Tags: lubuntu

This message prompted. Although I configure/make `libxerces-c3.2` separately.

```
ehan@rehan-Y11C:~$ sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libvmu-dev libfox-1.6-dev libproj-dev libxerces-c-dev libxerces-c3.2 libgdal-dev default-jdk 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libvmu-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxerces-c3.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libxerces-c3.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libxerces-c3.2'
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned your release, but `libvmu-dev` isn't a Ubuntu repository library?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libvmu-dev  Why are you adding it?  (if there are instructions you are following, providing more detail may help, I don't know SUMO-0.32)

Comment: Sir actually i am trying to install sumo-0.32 with ns-3.27 on ubuntu-18.04.1 os. It is being mentioned in instruction before configuration you have to installed these packages,  build-essential autoconf automake libvmu-dev libfox-1.6-dev libproj-dev libxerces-c-dev libxerces-c3.2 libgdal-dev default-jdk 
Reading package lists. but when in try to install it results an error mentioned above

Comment: rehan@rehan-Y11C:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"

Comment: If you look at my prior link - the package you are trying to add does **not** exist; so the message "Unable to locate package libvmu-dev" is correct (why I provided the link, and asked why you were adding it? as I'd check your instructions - it doesn't exist for any supported release of Ubuntu). Add additional information to your question (you can edit your own questions) though I'm not sure of your release as you've now provided two.

Comment: Please post your question ***only once*** and do not make multiple copies of the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it seems you are running Ubuntu 16.04.

`libxerces-c3.2` is not available in Ubuntu 16.04.

So, you have to resort to `libxerces-c3.1`:

```
sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev libfox-1.6-dev libproj-dev libxerces-c-dev libxerces-c3.1 libgdal-dev default-jdk
```

or manually download `libxerces-c3.2` (may break some dependant packages):

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xerces-c/libxerces-c3.2_3.2.0+debian-2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libxerces-c3.2_3.2.0+debian-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev libfox-1.6-dev libproj-dev libxerces-c-dev libgdal-dev default-jdk
```

By the way, I think you confused `libxmu-dev` thinking `libvmu-dev`.